# Why is loading a list of contexts with Map Get not working?

Tags: packages, contexts, initialization, import, autoload

I wish to automate the loading of packages by using Map and Get but Mathematica doesn't seem to like it. How can I make this work?

This is how packages are normally loaded...

```
<< Testpack`
<< NBStyles`
<< NBUtilities`
<< NBTaskmate`
```

This is what I am trying to do...

```
$packages = {Testpack`, NBStyles`, NBUtilities`, NBTasknmate`};
Map[Get[#] &, $packages]
```

But it returns an error messaage...

```
Syntax::sntxf: "$packages=" cannot be followed by "{NBStyles`,NBUtilities`,NBTasknmate`,Testpack`}".
```

Comment: Get takes a string as input, not a symbol.

Comment: To expand in Daniel's comment, You can omit the " " only if you use the `<<` for of Get, and only if certain characters are present in the string (see details section of its documentation). Otherwise the input to get must be a `String` object, delimited by " ".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this be acceptable?

```
list1 = {"Testpack`", "NBStyles`", "NBUtilities`", "NBTasknmate`"}
Map[Get, list1]
```

Comment: @MarcoB yes that was very helpful thank you.